# How to create 1 row dataframe from a dataset in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a .csv file with many rows and columns. For analysis purposes, I want to select a row number from the dataset and pass it as a dataframe in pandas.

Instead of writing the column names and input values inside a dict, how can I make it faster?
Right now I have:

```
df= pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df2= pd.DataFrame({'var1': 5, 'var2': 10, 'var3': 15})
```

var1,var2,var3 are df columns. I want to make a seperate dataframe with df data.

You can either select a random row, or a given row number.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```py
df2 = df.iloc[rownum:rownum + 1, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out data as new dataframe from existing one you can use something like this -

based on particular rows required

```
df2 = df.iloc[4:5,:]
```

or data using some condition

```
df3 = df[df['var1'] < 10]
```